# Science fiction film/TV show about a plane about to crash, transferred somewhere, its passengers replaced with already dead people?

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

Science fiction film or tv show where a plane was about to crash, and the plane was transferred somewhere? And the live people were removed and replaced with already dead people before it crashed.

Was it on *The Twilight Zone* maybe?

Comment: That *sort of* describes the plot of *Lost*, from a certain perspective.

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53443/title-of-80s-movie-future-era-timetraveling-humans-go-extinct-and-rescue-kidna (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 44):

This would be [*Millennium*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_%28film%29) (1989):

> They are abducting people who will not be able to affect the future any further and replacing them with copies of those who would have died. Thus, the co-pilot's strange comment came because all the passengers had been replaced with pre-burned duplicates in preparation for the upcoming crash.

Comment: the book is way better.  read it!  John Varley is an amazing author.

Comment: http://www.unshelved.com/2012-6-29

Comment: The short story that Varley expanded to the novel is called "Air Raid", and it's better than the novel.

Comment: Baen has a free copy of "Air Raid" available online at http://www.baenebooks.com/chapters/9781625791542/9781625791542___3.htm

Comment: And apparently Varley's experience with the screenplay and movie production was such as to inspire a very unflattering satirical scene in the third of his Gaia novels, *Demon*.

Answer (score 8):

Kind of makes me think of [*The Langoliers*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112040/) (1995):

> Most of the passengers on an airplane disappear, and the remainder
>   land the plane in a mysteriously barren airport.

Comment: This was my firs thought too. (though I couldn't remember the name, thanks for that).

Answer (score 6):

It also makes me think of an episode of the new BBC series *Sherlock*, ["A scandal in Belgravia"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1942612/) (2012).  In the episode Sherlock comes across top secret information revolving around a plane full of dead people for some government conspiracy.

Comment: Many thanks the film was Millennium, excellent!

Comment: @user14911, then you should accept that answer by clicking the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds a bit as the first plot in [*The Event*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Event) (2010).

> Sean boards a plane and pleads with the pilot, Leila's father Michael , not to crash it into the President's press conference in Miami. As the plane approaches the press conference site, it flies into a vortex in mid-air and vanishes.

Afterwards, the plane is found with everyone inside dead, except they mysteriously revive later.