# Title of 80's movie: future-era timetraveling humans go extinct and rescue/kidnap todays air crash victims

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

What is the title of a 80's (i believe?) movie where humans in the far future are going extinct, and are aquiring new humans by going back in time to todays world, kidnapping air travelers that are known to have died that day, from the flying passenger aircraft just before its crashing.

A key visual:

[image: A key visual of a (flying) aircraft tail sticking out of a time portal.]

Inside a hangar, a time portal opened, and a tail of a (flying) passenger aircraft extruded into the hangar where a stairs provided access to the back door of the aircraft.

The kidnappers made sure the surviving passengers remain seated and would forget about the whole ordeal. Kidnapped humans got replaced by lookalike dummies, including things they had on them. They tried hard not to alter the timeline.

Comment: Nice use of illustrations.

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51080/ .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe by your description it is the 1989 film [MILLENIUM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_%28film%29) the key points match up to the films storyline

Comment: Beat me by 30 seconds!

Comment: Yes that must be it! I should have known about scifi.stackexchange.com sooner, its terrific.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the movie referred to is probably Millenium.

If memory serves well; the replacements where either human (like) 'blanks' or generic 'clones'. I am probably wrong on this!

Also, the rescued humans did not stay in the same 'root' time or place as their rescuers. Rather, they were sent to another time and / or place (possibly another planet) in order to restore the human race which was (by the root time) heading for extinction.

I'm going to have to buy Millenium now to find out!

Comment: It would be better for you to improve the other answer, but I'll give you the points for providing more information

Comment: Or read [the novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_(novel)) by John Varley.