# Looking for proper name of 1970s film the TV Show Continuum was based on

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to find the correct name of the movie that the *Continuum* TV show was loosely based on.

The movie's premise was a futuristic group of individuals who go back in time, and take bodies that are about to die.  They put them in storage to populate Earth or another planet later on in the future.  In one scene, an airplane lost an engine, and they were about to crash, when the future group of people pulled the plain into time portal, to extract the individuals off the plane and put them in stasis and replace them with dummies.  The only exception is a child who later becomes a detective.  During the extraction something goes wrong, and one of the future people lost their phaser/laser gun, and the leader of the group has to go back in time later on and remove the item before a paradox ensues.

Can anyone identify this movie? 
Thanks

Comment: The movie you are talking about was based on "Air Raid" by John Varley.  He later expanded it to the book, and later a screenplay, both called [Milleium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_%28novel%29).  That said, I've never heard a suggestion that Continuum was based on it; they have very little in common.

Comment: see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53443/title-of-80s-movie-future-era-timetraveling-humans-go-extinct-and-rescue-kidna -- does it sound the same?

Comment: Yes.  That's it.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Millenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_%28film%29) a 1989 sci-fi film has time travellers kidnapping doomed people from crashing airlines to help repopulate the future. One of them leaves a weapon behind that causes a time-line issue. The sole survivor of one of the crashes (and therefore not kidnapped) grows up to be an NTSB investigator and interacts with the time travellers.